# Analyze/ Improve the accuracy of CIFAR-100 model using Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm training a classification model (cifar-100) using a convolutional neural network to classify 60000 images into 100 classes (600 images per class).
When I trained the model for the first time without using any regularization technique

```
cifar100_model = Sequential()

cifar100_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(32, 32, 3), 
activation='relu'))
cifar100_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cifar100_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(32, 32, 3), 
activation='relu'))
cifar100_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cifar100_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(32, 32, 3), 
activation='relu'))
cifar100_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

cifar100_model.add(Flatten())

cifar100_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
cifar100_model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))

#Output Layer 
cifar100_model.add(Dense(100, activation="softmax"))
```

I got the following result:

Training accuracy — 52%
Validation accuracy — 37%
This suggests that the model is overfitting

I re-trained the model and this time I used dropout as a regularization technique

```
cifar100_model = Sequential()

cifar100_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(32, 32, 3), activation='relu'))
cifar100_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cifar100_model.add(Dropout(0.25))
cifar100_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(32, 32, 3), activation='relu'))
cifar100_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cifar100_model.add(Dropout(0.25))
cifar100_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(32, 32, 3), activation='relu'))
cifar100_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cifar100_model.add(Dropout(0.25))

cifar100_model.add(Flatten())

#Fully connected layers
cifar100_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
cifar100_model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))

#Output Layer (Fully connected)
cifar100_model.add(Dense(100, activation="softmax"))
```

I got the following results:

Training accuracy — 37%
Validation accuracy — 35%

How can I improve the model?
(Considering that the number of images per class is very low and the quality of images is poor)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `dropout` layer, try using `BatchNormalization()` layer with `Conv2d` layer. Also , you can change `optimizer`, increase number of `epochs` to get better accuracy.

Here what I have replicated and found better `accuracy`:

```
cifar100_model = Sequential()

cifar100_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=(2, 2), input_shape=(32, 32, 3), activation='relu'))
cifar100_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cifar100_model.add(BatchNormalization())
cifar100_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
cifar100_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cifar100_model.add(BatchNormalization())
cifar100_model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size=(2, 2),activation='relu'))
cifar100_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cifar100_model.add(BatchNormalization())

cifar100_model.add(Flatten())

#Fully connected layers
cifar100_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
cifar100_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
cifar100_model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
cifar100_model.add(Dropout(0.2))

#Output Layer (Fully connected)
cifar100_model.add(Dense(100, activation="softmax"))

cifar100_model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),metrics=['accuracy'])
history = cifar100_model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=70, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

Output:

```
Epoch 60/70
1563/1563 [==============================] - 8s 5ms/step - loss: 0.5905 - accuracy: 0.8195 - val_loss: 3.0412 - val_accuracy: 0.4311
Epoch 61/70
1563/1563 [==============================] - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.5958 - accuracy: 0.8159 - val_loss: 3.1160 - val_accuracy: 0.4278
Epoch 62/70
1563/1563 [==============================] - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.5824 - accuracy: 0.8207 - val_loss: 3.0850 - val_accuracy: 0.4341
Epoch 63/70
1563/1563 [==============================] - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.5749 - accuracy: 0.8209 - val_loss: 3.2525 - val_accuracy: 0.4323
Epoch 64/70
1563/1563 [==============================] - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.5797 - accuracy: 0.8205 - val_loss: 3.0821 - val_accuracy: 0.4366
Epoch 65/70
1563/1563 [==============================] - 8s 5ms/step - loss: 0.5664 - accuracy: 0.8236 - val_loss: 3.1441 - val_accuracy: 0.4333
Epoch 66/70
1563/1563 [==============================] - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.5639 - accuracy: 0.8271 - val_loss: 3.0761 - val_accuracy: 0.4368
Epoch 67/70
1563/1563 [==============================] - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.5646 - accuracy: 0.8266 - val_loss: 3.2371 - val_accuracy: 0.4368
Epoch 68/70
1563/1563 [==============================] - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.5604 - accuracy: 0.8263 - val_loss: 3.1636 - val_accuracy: 0.4271
Epoch 69/70
1563/1563 [==============================] - 9s 5ms/step - loss: 0.5554 - accuracy: 0.8269 - val_loss: 3.2159 - val_accuracy: 0.4296
Epoch 70/70
1563/1563 [==============================] - 9s 6ms/step - loss: 0.5439 - accuracy: 0.8329 - val_loss: 3.2745 - val_accuracy: 0.4291
```

You can refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#demonstrate_overfitting) link to know more about other methodologies to be used to overcome with `overfitting` problem.